# Fastest way of converting image to grayscale using certain coefficients

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I need to convert a `cv::Mat` into grayscale using a custom formula. Each channel of the input matrix has to be multiplied by a certain coefficient.

This is a pseudocode of the operation:

```
Y = 0.2126*R + 0.7152*G + 0.0722*B
```

Input matrix is `CV_32FC3` and output has to be `CV_32FC1.`

Simple looping using 2 for cycles and computing each pixel sequentially seems to be not fast enough.

```
int rows = src.rows, cols = src.cols;
for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++){
    const float* src_ptr = src.ptr<float>(row);
    float* dst_ptr = dst.ptr<float>(row);

    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++){
        dst_ptr[col] = ( 0.0722 * src_ptr[0] ) + ( 0.7152 * src_ptr[1] ) + ( 0.2126 * src_ptr[2]);
        src_ptr += 3;
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I was hoping to use `parallel_for_` cycle but I can't figure it out by my own.

This is the not working solution i have been working on:

```
void MyOperator::getIntensity(const cv::Mat& src, cv::Mat& dst){
    int nElements = src.cols * src.rows;
    parallel_for_(cv::Range(0,nElements) , BGR2rec709Parallel((float*)src.data, (float*)dst.data));
}

class BGR2rec709Parallel : public cv::ParallelLoopBody
{
private:
    float *src;
    float *dst;
public:
    BGR2rec709Parallel(float* src_ptr, float* dst_ptr) : src(src_ptr), dst(dst_ptr) {}

    virtual void operator()( const cv::Range &r ) const
    {
        for (int i = r.start; i != r.end; ++i)
        {
            dst[i] = ( 0.0722 * src[i] ) + ( 0.7152 * src[i+1] ) + ( 0.2126 * src[i+2]);
        }
    }
    virtual ~BGR2rec709Parallel();
};
```

Comment: Please show the working but too slow code as a foundation for answers. I.e. please make a [mcve]

Comment: "seems to be not fast enough" for what? Is it, or isn't it? How do you verify whether a proposed solution is fast enough?

Comment: Why don't you use `cv::cvtColor();`.

Comment: I use a parallel_for_ loop to `pow(2, each_pixel)` in other part of my project which sped it up. I was hoping to achieve similar result with the grayscale conversion.

Comment: `cv::cvtColor();` does not allow to use custom coefficients. `CV_BGR2GRAY` uses a different formula for conversion.

Comment: You can find more about [color conversion](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html) in this link.

Comment: And [here too](https://www.learnopencv.com/color-spaces-in-opencv-cpp-python/).

Comment: @SenDjasni I've read the resources, but I am not sure how it applies to my problem. I need to use a conversion according to the ITU Rec. 709 which specifies coefficients as mentioned in my original post.

Comment: You forget that the `src` pointer needs to move by 3 elements per iteration. `src[i]` should be `src[i*3]`, and so on..

Comment: [This code](https://github.com/udacity/cs344/blob/master/Problem%20Sets/Problem%20Set%201/reference_calc.cpp) does something similar. It could be useful to you.

Comment: @SenDjasni OP already has something equivalent to that (see the first part of the question). The problem is why the parallel version doesn't work correctly, which (as I explained) is due to incorrect indexing of the source.

Comment: @user3501283 You will probably gain some performance by making the coefficients floats instead of doubles (e.g. `0.0722f` instead of `0.0722`).

Comment: @DanMašek thanks. Moving the pointer did the trick! Please post it as an answer so i can accept it. The speed was increased approx. 2x and 2.5x with usage of floats coefficients (compared to sequential for cycles for 1920x1080 images).

Comment: @user3501283 OK. Few other comments. | Avoid C-style casts (The `(float*)` ought to be a `reinterpret_cast<float>`)... although why not `src.ptr<float>()` like you did earlier? | `src_ptr` and `src` don't need to allow modification. | The parallel version doesn't support non-continuous `Mat`s, but the old version did. | I'd set the range for parallel_for_ to `cv::Range(0,src.rows)` and handle whole rows in `operator()`. Right now the granularity ends up too find and can hinder performance (YMMV).

Comment: you could change opencv code to use your coefficients in cvtColor and compile opencv with all optimizations like sse instructions etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you don't index the source data correctly.

```
for (int i = r.start; i != r.end; ++i)
{
    dst[i] = ( 0.0722 * src[i] )
           + ( 0.7152 * src[i+1] )
           + ( 0.2126 * src[i+2]);
}
```

Let's imagine `r.start == 0` and `r.end == 2`. This code is then equivalent to:

```
dst[0] = ( 0.0722 * src[0] ) + ( 0.7152 * src[1] ) + ( 0.2126 * src[2]);
dst[1] = ( 0.0722 * src[1] ) + ( 0.7152 * src[2] ) + ( 0.2126 * src[3]);
```

Notice that values from `src` end up being reused -- this is certainly not desirable. The problem is that `src` contains 3x as many values as `dst`, hence its index should grow 3x faster.

```
for (int i = r.start; i != r.end; ++i)
{
    dst[i] = ( 0.0722 * src[i * 3] )
           + ( 0.7152 * src[i * 3 + 1] )
           + ( 0.2126 * src[i * 3 + 2]);
}
```

This should make the parallelized version work correctly, however there are more things to improve upon.

---

A noticeable improvement (~30% in the single thread version, ~10% in parallel version) can be made by making the coefficients `float` instead of `double` (e.g. `0.0722f` instead of `0.0722`). This is at cost of some precision, but avoids unnecessary conversions (and can potentially vectorize better).

---

Don't use C-style casts. In `BGR2rec709Parallel((float*)src.data, (float*)dst.data)` you should use `reinterpret_cast<float>`. Or even better, as you used in the first version, take advantage of `cv::Mat::ptr` (i.e. `src.ptr<float>()`, `dst.ptr<float>()`).

---

The way you use [`parallel_for_`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gaa42ec9937b847cb52a97c613fc894c4a) is not ideal:

```
int nElements = src.cols * src.rows;
parallel_for_(cv::Range(0, nElements), /* ... */);
```

You don't specify the third parameter (`nstripes`). Based on my observations (OpenCV 3.1.0/MSVS2013 and 3.4.3/MSVC2015), the result is that the `operator()` is called  with ranges of size 1. This can cause some rather nasty overhead, especially when range of size 1 corresponds to a single pixel.

Significant improvement can be seen by setting `nstripes` to `cv::getNumThreads()`. This will cause the work the be split up to 1 range per worker thread, with the ranges of similar sizes.

---

The parallel version can no longer handle discontinuous `Mat`s (e.g. result of taking a ROI of a bigger image), which the first version did.

To solve this, `parallel_for_` should work with rows instead of pixels, and its context should be references to the input and output `Mat`s instead of data pointers.

Splitting the work into number of stripes equal to thread count is not as important here, since processing a row already comprises a significant amount of work, but we can still do that.

---

Oh, one more to mention. `for (int i = r.start; i != r.end; ++i)` -- the `!=` here is asking for trouble in case you increase `i` by more than 1. Prefer to use `<` here.

---

The final version looks like this:

```
class BGR2rec709ParallelC
    : public cv::ParallelLoopBody
{
public:
    BGR2rec709ParallelC(cv::Mat const& src, cv::Mat& dst)
        : src(src), dst(dst)
    {
        CV_Assert(src.type() == CV_32FC3);
        CV_Assert(dst.type() == CV_32FC1);
        CV_Assert(src.size() == dst.size());
    }

    virtual void operator()(const cv::Range &r) const
    {
        for (int row(r.start); row < r.end; ++row) {
            convert_row(src.ptr<float>(row), dst.ptr<float>(row));
        }
    }

private:
    void convert_row(float const* src_ptr, float * dst_ptr) const
    {
        for (int i(0); i != src.cols; ++i) {
            dst_ptr[i] = (0.0722f * src_ptr[i * 3])
                + (0.7152f * src_ptr[i * 3 + 1])
                + (0.2126f * src_ptr[i * 3 + 2]);
        }
    }

private:
    cv::Mat const& src;
    cv::Mat& dst;
};

void get_intensity_v4(cv::Mat const& src, cv::Mat& dst)
{
    parallel_for_(cv::Range(0, src.rows)
        , BGR2rec709ParallelC(src, dst)
        , cv::getNumThreads());
}
```

---

Complete test program comparing the performance of various implementations:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

void get_intensity_base(cv::Mat const& src, cv::Mat& dst)
{
    cv::cvtColor(src, dst, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
}

void get_intensity_v1a(cv::Mat const& src, cv::Mat& dst)
{
    int rows = src.rows, cols = src.cols;
    for (int row(0); row < rows; ++row) {
        float const* src_ptr = src.ptr<float>(row);
        float* dst_ptr = dst.ptr<float>(row);

        for (int col(0); col < cols; ++col, src_ptr += 3) {
            dst_ptr[col] = static_cast<float>((0.0722 * src_ptr[0])
                + (0.7152 * src_ptr[1])
                + (0.2126 * src_ptr[2]));
        }
    }
}

void get_intensity_v1b(cv::Mat const& src, cv::Mat& dst)
{
    int rows = src.rows, cols = src.cols;
    for (int row(0); row < rows; ++row) {
        float const* src_ptr = src.ptr<float>(row);
        float* dst_ptr = dst.ptr<float>(row);

        for (int col(0); col < cols; ++col, src_ptr += 3) {
            dst_ptr[col] = (0.0722f * src_ptr[0])
                + (0.7152f * src_ptr[1])
                + (0.2126f * src_ptr[2]);
        }
    }
}

class BGR2rec709ParallelA
    : public cv::ParallelLoopBody
{
public:
    BGR2rec709ParallelA(float const* src, float* dst) : src(src), dst(dst) {}

    virtual void operator()(cv::Range const& r) const
    {
        for (int i(r.start); i < r.end; ++i) {
            dst[i] = static_cast<float>((0.0722 * src[i * 3])
                + (0.7152 * src[i * 3 + 1])
                + (0.2126 * src[i * 3 + 2]));
        }
    }
private:
    float const* src;
    float* dst;
};

class BGR2rec709ParallelB
    : public cv::ParallelLoopBody
{
public:
    BGR2rec709ParallelB(float const* src, float* dst) : src(src), dst(dst) {}

    virtual void operator()(cv::Range const& r) const
    {
        for (int i(r.start); i < r.end; ++i) {
            dst[i] = (0.0722f * src[i * 3])
                + (0.7152f * src[i * 3 + 1])
                + (0.2126f * src[i * 3 + 2]);
        }
    }
private:
    float const* src;
    float* dst;
};

template <typename LoopBody>
void get_intensity_v2(cv::Mat const& src, cv::Mat& dst)
{
    int nElements = src.cols * src.rows;
    parallel_for_(cv::Range(0, nElements)
        , LoopBody(src.ptr<float>(), dst.ptr<float>()));
}

template <typename LoopBody>
void get_intensity_v3(cv::Mat const& src, cv::Mat& dst)
{
    int nElements = src.cols * src.rows;
    parallel_for_(cv::Range(0, nElements)
        , LoopBody(src.ptr<float>(), dst.ptr<float>())
        , cv::getNumThreads());
}

class BGR2rec709ParallelC
    : public cv::ParallelLoopBody
{
public:
    BGR2rec709ParallelC(cv::Mat const& src, cv::Mat& dst)
        : src(src), dst(dst)
    {
        CV_Assert(src.type() == CV_32FC3);
        CV_Assert(dst.type() == CV_32FC1);
        CV_Assert(src.size() == dst.size());
    }

    virtual void operator()(const cv::Range &r) const
    {
        for (int row(r.start); row < r.end; ++row) {
            convert_row(src.ptr<float>(row), dst.ptr<float>(row));
        }
    }

private:
    void convert_row(float const* src_ptr, float * dst_ptr) const
    {
        for (int i(0); i != src.cols; ++i) {
            dst_ptr[i] = (0.0722f * src_ptr[i * 3])
                + (0.7152f * src_ptr[i * 3 + 1])
                + (0.2126f * src_ptr[i * 3 + 2]);
        }
    }

private:
    cv::Mat const& src;
    cv::Mat& dst;
};

void get_intensity_v4(cv::Mat const& src, cv::Mat& dst)
{
    parallel_for_(cv::Range(0, src.rows)
        , BGR2rec709ParallelC(src, dst)
        , cv::getNumThreads());
}

cv::Mat test(std::string const& name
    , cv::Mat const& input
    , void(*fn)(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&))
{
    cv::Mat output(input.size(), CV_32FC1); // pre-allocate

    std::cout << name << "\n";
    int64 min_ticks(0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF);
    for (int i(0); i < 32; ++i) {
        int64 t_start(cv::getTickCount());
        fn(input, output);
        int64 t_stop(cv::getTickCount());
        min_ticks = std::min(min_ticks, t_stop - t_start);
    }
    std::cout << " >= " << min_ticks << " ticks\n";

    return output;
}

cv::Mat3f make_test_data(int rows, int cols)
{
    cv::Mat m(rows, cols, CV_16UC3);
    cv::randu(m, 0, 0x10000);
    cv::Mat3f result;
    m.convertTo(result, CV_32FC3, 1.0 / 0xFFFF);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    cv::Mat input(make_test_data(4096, 4096));

    test("Base", input, get_intensity_base);

    cv::Mat out_v1a = test("V1A", input, get_intensity_v1a);
    cv::Mat out_v1b = test("V1B", input, get_intensity_v1b);

    cv::Mat out_v2a = test("V2A", input, get_intensity_v2<BGR2rec709ParallelA>);
    cv::Mat out_v2b = test("V2B", input, get_intensity_v2<BGR2rec709ParallelB>);

    cv::Mat out_v3a = test("V3A", input, get_intensity_v3<BGR2rec709ParallelA>);
    cv::Mat out_v3b = test("V3B", input, get_intensity_v3<BGR2rec709ParallelB>);

    cv::Mat out_v4 = test("V4", input, get_intensity_v4);

    std::cout << "Differences V1A vs V2A: " << cv::countNonZero(out_v1a != out_v2a) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Differences V1B vs V2B: " << cv::countNonZero(out_v1b != out_v2b) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Differences V1B vs V3B: " << cv::countNonZero(out_v1b != out_v3b) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Differences V1B vs V4: " << cv::countNonZero(out_v1b != out_v4) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

---

Console output (OpenCV 3.1.0/MSVC2013/x64/i7-4930K):

```
Base
 >= 126365 ticks
V1A
 >= 500890 ticks
V1B
 >= 331197 ticks
V2A
 >= 746851 ticks
V2B
 >= 704011 ticks
V3A
 >= 148181 ticks
V3B
 >= 134176 ticks
V4
 >= 133750 ticks
Differences V1A vs V2A: 0
Differences V1B vs V2B: 0
Differences V1B vs V3B: 0
Differences V1B vs V4: 0
```

---

Console output (OpenCV 3.4.3/MSVC2015/x64/i7-4930K):

```
Base
 >= 123620 ticks
V1A
 >= 503707 ticks
V1B
 >= 331801 ticks
V2A
 >= 1768515 ticks
V2B
 >= 1710579 ticks
V3A
 >= 145451 ticks
V3B
 >= 135767 ticks
V4
 >= 131438 ticks
Differences V1A vs V2A: 0
Differences V1B vs V2B: 0
Differences V1B vs V3B: 0
Differences V1B vs V4: 0
```

Note: Notice how much worse the fine granularity `parallel_for_` versions are here!

---

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by [Nuzhny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10911905/nuzhny), here's an implementation using [`cv::Mat::forEach`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a952ef1a85d70a510240cb645a90efc0d) along with a lambda.

```
void get_intensity_v5(cv::Mat const& src, cv::Mat& dst)
{
    CV_Assert(src.type() == CV_32FC3);
    CV_Assert(dst.type() == CV_32FC1);
    CV_Assert(src.size() == dst.size());

    dst.forEach<float>(
        [&](float& pixel, int const* po) -> void
        {
            cv::Vec3f const& in_pixel(src.at<cv::Vec3f>(po));
            pixel = (0.0722f * in_pixel[0])
                + (0.7152f * in_pixel[1])
                + (0.2126f * in_pixel[2]);
        }
    );
}
```

**Additional Console Output:**

```
V5
 >= 123071 ticks

Differences V1B vs V5: 0
```

And at this point, I honestly can't explain why this performs better -- `forEach` implementation used `parallel_for_` chunked by rows...

Comment: @Nuzhny OK, I'll update later today. I'd expect it to perform similarly to V4, since internally it uses `parallel_for_` chunked by rows.

Comment: @Nuzhny There you go, and well, bugger my sideways, but at this point I really don't see how this ends up faster. If you can run some tests on different compilers/hardware that would make a meaningful addition to this, feel free to edit them in to my answer.